# Scrape links using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I need to scrape every  Profile href link from:

```
<div class="avatar" style="height:85px; float: left; margin: 7px 0 7px 14px;">
        <span style="font-size: 8px">04.09.16 10:22:42</span>
        <br>
        <a href="/Profile/user_3383.html" alt="example" title="example">

    <img src="http://example.com/noimg.gif" alt="example" class="avatar">
        exampleNick
        </a>
    </div>
```

So I want to get: `/Profile/user_3383.html`

What I managed is:

```
HtmlUsers.LoadHtml(getRequest("http://example.com/users.html", cookieJar(30)))

                Dim getLink = HtmlUsers.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='avatar']/a/@href")

                For Each profileLink As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In getLink 
                    ListBox11.Items.Add(profileLink.InnerHtml)
                Next
```

But what I get is:

```
<img src="http://example.com/noimg.gif" alt="example" class="avatar"> exampleNick
```

Do you have any ideas why It does not giving me Profile href?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `<a>` elements first, and then add `href` attribute from each `<a>` to the `ListBox` :

```
Dim getLink = HtmlUsers.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='avatar']/a[@href]")

For Each profileLink As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In getLink 
    ListBox11.Items.Add(profileLink.GetAttributeValue("href", ""))
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. My code was intuitive, and I still dont get it why does it not worked. It was working properly with using this site: http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi